# Cookie not getting sent by Chrome and withCredentials is true

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, cookies, cross-domain

Chrome is choosing not to send a Cookie header in a GET request.  I am overriding `XMLHTTPRequest` so that when a library calls `open()`, it calls the original implementation of `open()` and then sets `withCredentials = true`.

I have tried taking a netlog viewer session but that does not seem to show cookie related items.  I have tried different binding techniques but I do not think this problem is `this` context related.  The cookie shows up fine in the cookie list under Application in the browser tools. The domain is listed as `.mydomain.com`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   document.cookie = "ATOKEN=\"d=dflskdjflsdkfj=1,\"; Version=1; Domain=.mydomain.com; expires=Tues, 23 Jul 2019 20:54:04 GMT; Path=/";

   // library makes request to a-subdomain.mydomain.com

   var originalXMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;

   XMLHttpRequest = function ()
   {
     var xhr     = new originalXMLHttpRequest();
     var _httpOpen = xhr.open.bind(xhr);

     xhr.open = function (method, url, flag)
     {
       _httpOpen(method, url, flag ? flag : true);

       if (url.indexOf('a-subdomain') >= 0)
       {
         xhr.withCredentials = true;
       }
     };

     return xhr;
   };
</script>
```

Using a Charles proxy to see 403'ed request and notice that Cookie header is not present.  Cookie header should be there with Cookie: ...

Comment: When you send a request with `withCredentials` true, the browser sends an OPTIONS preflight request first, and the server must respond to that OPTIONS request with an `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` response header, along with all other required CORS headers. Do you see an OPTIONS request being made, and if so, how is the server responding? If there's no OPTIONS preflight, then it sounds like you might have just a generic problem with your cookie (e.g., it's not labeled to be sent to your target domain)

Comment: I do not see an `OPTIONS` preflight request in the Chrome network calls.  The server is responding to the `GET` with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://a-subdomain.mydomain.com` and `403` status.  Maybe there is a problem with the cookie then.

Comment: You need to make sure the server you’re sending the request to allows unauthenticated OPTIONS requests. A CORS-enabled server will basically always respond to OPTIONS requests with a 200 OK — even when the requests never contain credentials (because browsers never send any credentials as part of the CORS preflight OPTIONS request). But the server in this case is responding to an OPTIONS request with a 403. That basically should never happen if the server is properly CORS-enabled. So the first fix here is to make the server respond with a 200 OK to OPTIONS requests.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by setting `withCredentials` to `true` "before send" instead of "after open".  In `xhr.send()` before the `_httpSend()` is called, the xhr object had its `withCredentials` property set back at `false`, even though it was getting set to `true` in `xhr.open()`.

I double-checked that the the xhr object was the same object in both methods and that the property was actually getting set to to `true` inside each method.  Somehow the `withCredentials` was getting reset in between calls to `xhr.open` and `xhr.send`. So I just made sure to set it to `true` in `xhr.send` right before the request is sent.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.cookie = 'ATOKEN=\"d=dflskdjflsdkfj=1,\"; domain=.mydomain.com;';

    // library makes request to a-subdomain.mydomain.com

    var originalXMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;

    XMLHttpRequest = function ()
    {
      var xhr     = new originalXMLHttpRequest();
      var _httpOpen = xhr.open.bind(xhr);
      var _httpSend = xhr.send.bind(xhr);

      var _url;

      xhr.open = function (method, url, flag)
      {
        _url = url;

        _httpOpen(method, url, flag ? flag : true);
      };

      xhr.send = function (body)
      {

        if (_url && _url.indexOf('a-subdomain') >= 0)
        {
          xhr.withCredentials = true;
        }

        _httpSend(body);
      };

      return xhr;
    };
</script>
```

I do not know why this property was getting reset as the methods in the  [XMLHTTPRequest Standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) do not touch that property.  Perhaps it is getting reset in the third-party Javascript I was overriding and I don't have access to.